# Parse error no código

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede-social\login.php on line 46

```
<?php
    include("db.php");

    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $pass = $_POST['pass'];
       $verifica = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'
       If (mysql_num_rows($verifica)<=0) {
           echo '<h3>Email ou Senha Incorretos!</h3>';
       }else{
          setcookie('login',$email);
          header('location: ./');
       }

     }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>CloseFriend - Fazer Login</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <style type='text/css'>
   *{margin:0;padding:0;font-family: Arial;}
   body{text-align: center;}
   .logo{font-family: Lobster;color:#000000;font-size: 50px;margin:20px 0;}
   form{margin:20px 0;}
   input[type='text'],form input[type='password']{width:250px;height:40px;border:1px solid #999;padding:0 5px;border-radius:4px;margin:8px 0;font-size:17px;}
   input[type='submit']{width:260px;height:40px;border:1px solid #999;padding:0 5px;border-radius:4px;margin:8px 0;font-size:17px;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;background:#999;font-size:17px;cursor:pointer;}
   form h3{margin:20px 0;color:#999}
   form a{color:#000;text-decoration: none;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
     <h1 class='logo'>CloseFriend</h1>
     <form method='POST'>
       <h2>Acessar sua conta</h2>
       <input type='email' placeholder='Digite seu E-mail'><br />
       <input type='password' placeholder='Senha'><br />
       <input type='submit' value=' Login'>
      </form>
      <h3>Não tem uma conta? <a href='login.php'>Criar uma conta</a></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'` falta um `);`, erro ao colocar no site ou está assim mesmo?

Comment: Onde é a linha 46? Por favor, edite a pergunta e forneça mais informações.

Comment: Considere usar [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) para não estar vulnerável a ataques de MySql injection. Deve também escrever os `if` em minusculas por consistência.

Comment: Na linha "$verifica = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'"

deve adicionar um "); no final

E troque o If por if

Answer (score 4):

De:

```
$verifica = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'
```

Para

```
$verifica = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
```

Resolvido não?

Além do mais guarde esta mensagem dentro de um `array`:

```
echo '<h3>Email ou Senha Incorretos!</h3>';
```

Desta forma:

```
$error[] = '<h3>Email ou Senha Incorretos!</h3>';
```

Use `foreach` para recuperar a mensagem, exemplo:

```
if(isset($error)) {
  foreach($error as $e) {
    echo $e;
  }
}
```

Obs: coloque este `foreach` dentro do `HTML`.

O seu `input`, diminuiu, certo, eu vi que você estilizou, `inputs`, `text`, `password`, mas não estilizou `input email`

Comment: Neste caso pode ser só uma variável mesmo. Claro que com o *array* fica mais versátil para incluir novas mensagens, mas atualmente seria desnecessário.

Comment: Bom, eu acho melhor, além do mais, ela pode fazer futuras verificações, como, campo em branco, essas coisas, e acrescentar a mensagem.

Comment: onde coloco essa parte?if(isset($error)) {
  foreach($error as $e) {
    echo $e;
  }
}

Comment: Pode ser acima de `</body>`, lembre-se de abrir as tags `<?php ?>`

Comment: <h3>Não tem uma conta? <a href='login.php'>Criar uma conta</a></h3>
      if(isset($error)) {
  foreach($error as $e) {
    echo $e;
  }
}
</body>
</html> assim?

Comment: Isto mesmo, veja se funciona e comente aqui.

Comment: Gente, desculpem minha ignorancia, to começando agr com os codigos rsrs

Comment: O importante é tentar e conseguir, mas lembre-se pesquisar antes de fazer qualquer pergunta é fundamental. Se foi resolvido. Marque a resposta como resolvido.

Comment: Foi aqui gente. Valeu pela ajuda de vcs

Comment: @JulianaLuiz clique no sinal de resolvido na resposta... esta é a forma de agradecer aqui na comunidade.

Comment: onde fica isso?

Comment: Veja: http://prntscr.com/fse4m8

Answer (score 3):

Você colocou o código todo dentro de uma string e o `if` com o "I" maiúsculo. Para consertar, é só colocar as `"(aspas)` no final da string que você quer e trocar o `If` por `if`:

```
<?php
    include("db.php");

    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $pass = $_POST['pass'];
       $verifica = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
       if (mysql_num_rows($verifica)<=0) {
           echo '<h3>Email ou Senha Incorretos!</h3>';
       }else{
          setcookie('login',$email);
          header('location: ./');
       }
     }
?>
```

Além disso, recomendo usar ou o [`Mysqli`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) ou o [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) ao invés do `mysql_`, já que [ele está obsoleto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql) nas versões mais novas do PHP.

Note também que seu CSS está estilizando somente os inputs do tipo `text` e `password`, para consertar o tamanho da caixa de e-mail, você deve adicioná-la ao CSS:

```css
input[type='text'], form input[type='password'], form input[type='email'] {
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Comment: Pode comentar o fato de estar sendo feito um `echo` de um elemento `h3` fora do documento HTML em si. Ele é exibido, mas não faz sentido algum fazer isso.